# php on ubuntu proc_open command error with python

Tags: php, python, linux, ubuntu, ssl

i faced this problem while i was trying to use **youtube-dl by php on ubuntu**.

> **I am using XAMPP for Linux v1.8.3 (PHP 5.5.9)**

---

The error i received after executing:

> {"status":0,"errors":"Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   \"/usr/bin/youtube-dl\", line 3, in  import youtube_dl File
>   \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/_*init*_.py\",
>   line 65, in  from .utils import ( File
>   \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/utils.py\", line
>   18, in  import ssl File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py\", line 61, in
>   import _ssl # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
>   ImportError:
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol
>   GENERAL_NAME_free, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file
>   libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference

And this is my php code

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFQFMSNZW08&list=RDV-jLo0Ovems';
    //escapeshellarg
    $string = ('youtube-dl --max-quality 2180 --write-thumbnail -x --audio-format mp3 -c -o "/home/bahaa/%(id)s.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFQFMSNZW08&list=RDV-jLo0Ovems');

    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
        2 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stderr
    );

    $process = proc_open($string, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    $ret = proc_close($process);
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'status' => $ret,
            'errors' => str_replace(array('', "\n"), "<br />", $stderr."<hr />"),
            'output' => $stdout,
        )
    );
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is a problem with python-driven `youtube-dl`, so you'd better change this question to a problem with `youtube-dl` and post your traceback in more readable way. There seems to be no php problem right here

Comment: No brother it is not with youtube-dl, because youtube-dl works fine from gnome-terminal i only get that error when i use it with php

Comment: Did you try to run it using `system` or `shell_exec`?

Comment: with shell_exec yep was the same